# Joining different table on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables, Student, Staff, Transport, In transport table there are records of students and staff who have transport and are differentiated from `CandidateType` column. If `CandidateType = 0` record must come from staff table and if `CandidateType=1` then record must come from Student Table. The Problem is that the joining column in both tables have same values. Below is the structure of my tables.

```
|Staff Table|
-------------------------
Id | Name | Designation |
-------------------------
1  | ABC  | Teacher     |
2  | xyz  | Clerk       |
3  | DDD  | Teacher     |

Student Table
Id | Name | Class |
-------------------
1 | Ali   | 5th   |
2 | Khan  | 6th   |
3 | Jan   | 6th   |

Transport Table
Id | CandidateId | Candiadate Type | VehicleId
----------------------------------------------
1  |  1          | 0               |  1
2  |  3          | 1               |  1
3  |  2          | 1               |  1
```

I want to retrieve record of students and Staff in `VehicleId=1.`
In `transport` table candidateIds are same in both Staff and Student Table, how to get the record of `students` and `staff` in vehicle one. 
Any help.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        CASE WHEN CandidateType = 0 
            THEN b.Name
            ELSE c.Name
        END AS Name
FROM    Transport a
        LEFT JOIN Staff b
            ON  a.CandidateID = b.ID
        LEFT JOIN   Student c
            ON a.CandidateID = c.ID
WHERE   a.VehicleID = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/12c25/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦══════╗
║ ID ║ NAME ║
╠════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ ABC  ║
║  2 ║ Jan  ║
║  3 ║ Khan ║
╚════╩══════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  *
from    Transport tr
left join
        Staff stf
on      stf.Id = tr.CandidateId 
        and tr.CandidateType = 0
left join
        Student stu
on      stu.Id = tr.CandidateId 
        and tr.CandidateType = 1
```